How to accept death?
How would you accept death? Many people will interpret this question as "How to overcome the fear of death?". As far as I know, there is no way to truly overcome death. “In my arrogance, I thought that I could conquer death with logic. But now I know that I only used logic to suppress my fear of death.”. People say that they have overcome death and it might be for the people who fought wars but people have different mentalities on the battlefield. I and most other people will most likely die a slow death and when you die a slow death, Death brings a different kind of fear.
I want to know how to accept that death or change my perspective on the concept of death.

This is the point of all religion. Jesus resurrects so that gives hope (to christians) that there's a way out. Likewise Buddha started on his way after the 4 sights, the critical one being a dead body.  It is so across the board. All major religions start and end with addressing death. So my advice to you: Turn to the religion that's most accessible to you. Note religion is not to be taken narrowly: Even Socrates showed exceptional courage and good humor as he drank the poison. His support was philodophy!

One more suggestion: Watch the movie Man for all seasons. Also here is an answer to a similar question

@Rushi I mean no offense but religion has done more bad than good in my family. My family is still religious but I am not. But I still believe in my religious morals but not the religion itself and none of the afterlife are appealing to me. That is why I asked how to accept death. Afterlife is just us trying to comfort ourselves. That is why many people kill themselves hoping for a better afterlife (if there is any) than their current life or just end their meaningless existence. I am more interested in having a different view on death.

There are many to choose from... if yours doesn't work... IF!  Have you seriously tried to study it from better scholars than your family? If you've done that conscientiously then sure, you can fish with a wider net. That's when philosophy comes in

I suspect that most suicides are not in hope of a better afterlife, but are due to inability to cope with this one to the degree that even nothingness is preferable. But obviously I cannot speak for those who have attempted suicide, never mind those who have succeeded. I've been close enough to know that it isn't in my spectrum of likely responses unless it is unlikely that I will ever recover an adequate quality of life.

How to accept death strikes me as being a better question for a psychology forum than a philosophy forum. Searching for broad truths will not help you. Searching for your own truths, even if not shared by anyone else, might. Psychiatric treatment might help more, depending on exactly what you are trying to cope with.

@keshlam Death is the utter absence of suffering

Death is bad. It is correct to be averse to it. I suggest that what you're looking for is courage, not lack of fear. Courage is a skill and a habit. You get it by practice.

Are talking from experience @JD? Note that Buddha contradicts you — if nirvana is not attained, death will not end suffering. You need to give some reasons why we must believe your evidence over the Buddha's

@Rush Reincarnation is a pleasant dream. Death is the end,  of course.

You're repeating yourself @JD. And Buddha foresaw these and such objections. He did not suggest that the illusion of self is lasting — anatta.  What he suggested that if there is a great deal of inertial velocity in the mind, that inertia by conservation of momentum must find a new physical sustrate

@Rushi It's a lovely thought,  indeed.

You fear death because you are attached to the idea of yourself and your image, your memories, your desires. But death is natural, it is part of the cycle.
When you live fully in the present, without clinging to the past or worrying about the future, you begin to see that death is not something separate from life. It’s simply a change, a continuation.
Accepting death comes when you understand that the fear of it comes from your attachment to things that are fleeting, You let go of that, then you can accept death as it is.
